# Create ID and Display when saved in Power Apps

Tags: onedrive, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am looking to save entries in OneDrive excel from Power Apps once entered,

For saving I used the following code:

```
Patch(
   Records,
   Defaults(Records),
   {
       Unit:'User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value,
       Application:'User Input - Application'.Selected.Value
   }
)
```

How can I save records with a sequence of number Eg "AM-2023XX" and increment by "1" for each entry?

Also once the number is generated it should get displayed for the user for future reference.

Comment: You would need to store the next sequence number, retrieve it from Power Apps, use it in your Patch statement, then increment and store the next sequence number.  I'm not sure if you can do this with Excel.  I've done something similar with SharePoint and SQL Server.

Comment: Can you guide me how to do it in sharepoint.